# Bootstrap Mobile menu toggle class when menu open and close

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a X icon when the menu is open on Bootstrap v3.3.4 mobile menu and also if click outside of the menu it should close and change the icon to its default.

But I have successfully added the X icon on the menu but failed to add the click outside action. when click outside it close the menu but not change the icon

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".navbar-toggle").on("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
   $(document).on('click',function(){
      if ($('.navbar-toggle').hasClass('active') ) {
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
      }
  });
});
```

Here is the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rupomkhondaker/3h2mddz5/) of my code please have a look.

Comment: Most likely, you need to listen for the Bootstrap events for collapse: [version 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#events) or [version 3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse-events)

Comment: Bootstrap v3.3.4

Comment: Those are links - refer to the one matching your BS version (there are no docs specifically for 3.3.4 - read the latest 3.x docs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).toggleClass("active");` inside the `$(document).on("click")` will not contain the `.navbar-toggle` class. But it will hold the `document` element. Because `this` is inside another function.

Also, you have to check if you didn't click the element itself. If you delete

```
if(!$(event.target).closest('.navbar-toggle').length)
```

The class gets added, but directly deleted. `if ($('.navbar-toggle').hasClass('active') )` returns true, because you added that class few lines before. So it deletes it.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".navbar-toggle").on("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
   $(document).on('click',function(){
   if(!$(event.target).closest('.navbar-toggle').length) {
      if ($('.navbar-toggle').hasClass('active') ) {
        $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
        $(".navbar-toggle").toggleClass("active");
      }
      }
  });
  
});
```

```css
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar:nth-of-type(2) {
   top: 1px;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar:nth-of-type(3) {
   top: 2px;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
   position: relative;
   transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-toggle.active .icon-bar:nth-of-type(1) {
   top: 6px;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.navbar-toggle.active .icon-bar:nth-of-type(2) {
   background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-toggle.active .icon-bar:nth-of-type(3) {
   top: -6px;
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Animated Burger, Bootstrap</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Np, I added a little explaination :)

Comment: I have added library to your answer so the snippet run directly here. :)